# Bing Maps Pushpins and Info Box

Tags: bing-maps

I had a problem in bing maps, any one solve my issue.

On my bing maps I had lot's of pushpins, some are very closer to each other. So, when I click on one pushpin, respective Infobox is opened, but closer pushpins are displayed on the Infobox opened. Those need to be hidden below that opened Infobox.

So,please help me to hide the inactive pushpins beside infobox

Answer (score 0):

I know exactly what your issue is. In bing Maps V7 the infobox entity is considered as just another entity like a pushpin, polygon, poliline... This is to make it more flexiable.That said, in most cases you want your infobox to always appear above your shapes. This can easily be done by using two entity collections. The bottom one for your shapes/pushpins and the top one for your infoboxes. I have a blog post demonstrating this here: http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/multiple-pushpins-and-infoboxes-in-bing-maps-v7/